# How to get the current active window in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: python, window, 22.04

I need to be able to get the current active Window's app name and page title in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (with Wayland desktop), no matter what the app is. I'll be implementing it in python, so something friendly to that environment would be wonderful!

The ways that work for me in previous versions of Ubuntu don't seem to work properly in 22.04. The ways that work in other Linux distros also don't seem to work in 22.04.

1. I've tried the following:

   ```
   xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW
   ```

   This gives me great information for Chromium, Firefox, Opera and Brave, but nothing else (not Terminal, System Monitor, Calculator, LibreOffice Writer, etc). Instead, for non-web-browsers, it seems to just return 0.
2. I've tried the gdbus call [here](https://gist.github.com/iberianpig/66e3a3cc5ba43064f384f6baa9fc3227) in python:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python3

   import subprocess

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       while 1 == 1:

           print('---------------')
           print('global.get_window_actors...')
           app_command = ("gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval global.get_window_actors\(\)[`gdbus call -e -d org.gnome.Shell -o /org/gnome/Shell -m org.gnome.Shell.Eval global.get_window_actors\(\).findIndex\(a\=\>a.meta_window.has_focus\(\)===true\) | cut -d\"'\" -f 2`].get_meta_window\(\).get_wm_class\(\)")
           app_process = subprocess.Popen(app_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
           app_retval = app_process.stdout.read()
           app_retcode = app_process.wait()
           actorsApp = app_retval.decode('utf-8').strip()
           print(actorsApp)

           time.sleep(1)
   ```

   This just consistently returns `(false, '')`, no matter what app is active.
3. I've tried Wnck, which returns this error:

   ```
   Wnck-WARNING **: libwnck is designed to work in X11 only, no valid display found
   ```
4. I tried combining these:

   ```
    xdpyinfo | grep focus
    xwininfo -root -tree
   ```

   But just like `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`, these gave me accurate info for web browsers in focus, but not other apps.
5. Looking at `wmctrl -lx` I see the same thing yet again, only web browsers are listed when open, not any other open apps.
6. The closest to success I've come is using `pyatspi` to track accessibility events. I had to specially turn on `GNOME_ACCESSIBILITY` in my `~/.profile` file to get Firefox to work with it.

   But once I had it up and running it seems to track everything properly **as long as the windows I want tracked are already open first**. However, if I open a new app (consistently Chromium, but other apps usually do the same thing too), then `pyatspi` seems to freeze. If I could get `pyatspi` to work right, that would be a sufficient solution for me, but with it freezing every time an app is opened, it just won't do. Here is my `pyatspi` code.

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

    import pyatspi
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    class PyatspiMonitor:
        app = ''
        title = ''
        focusMoment = None
        eventPrint = ''

        def getApplicationTitle(self, appName):
            print('getApplicationTitle() ' + str(datetime.now()))
            title = None
            try:
                if appName:
                    i = 0
                    desktopCount = pyatspi.Registry.getDesktopCount()
                    while i < desktopCount:
                        try:
                            desktop = pyatspi.Registry.getDesktop(i)
                            for application in desktop:
                                # While we do nothing with the attr data, it seems important
                                # to grab it for pyatspi to see Chromium correctly
                                try:
                                    attrs = str(node.getAttributes())
                                except:
                                    attrs = ''
                                if application and application.name and application.name.lower() == appName.lower():
                                    for node in application:
                                        title = node.name
                                        break
                                if title:
                                    break
                            desktop.setCacheMask(pyatspi.cache.NONE)
                            if title:
                                break
                        except:
                            pass
                        i = i + 1
            except Exception as e:
                print("getApplicationTitle() ERROR: " + str(e))
                title = None
            return title

        def onEvent(self, e):
            try:
                if self.app:
                    appname = ""
                    title = ''
                    try:
                        appname = str(e.host_application.name)
                    except:
                        appname = ""
                    # Make sure we don't override a valuable onFocus
                    # event with stuff that's less valuable
                    oneSecondAgo = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=1)
                    if (self.focusMoment and self.focusMoment < oneSecondAgo) or (not self.focusMoment):
                        if appname and appname.lower() == self.app.lower():
                            # This event is from the focused app
                            try:
                                title = str(e.source_name)
                            except:
                                title = ''
                        if not title:
                            # See if there's a meaningful change to the title of the active app
                            # since its last onFocus event
                            title = self.getApplicationTitle(self.app)
                        if title:
                            self.focusMoment = datetime.now()
                            self.title = title

                            toPrint = 'onEvent() RESULT: ' + self.app + ' - ' + self.title
                            if self.eventPrint != toPrint:
                                self.eventPrint = toPrint
                                print(toPrint)
            except Exception as e:
                print("onEvent() ERROR: " + str(e))
                pass

        def onFocus(self, e):
            try:
                # detail1 = 1 means this app received focus.
                # detail1 = 0 means focus left this app.
                if e.detail1:
                    appname = ""
                    try:
                        appname = str(e.host_application.name)
                    except:
                        appname = ""
                    if appname and appname.lower() != 'gnome-shell':
                        self.focusMoment = datetime.now()
                        self.app = appname
                        try:
                            title = str(e.source_name)
                        except:
                            title = None
                        if not title:
                            title = self.getApplicationTitle(appname)
                        if not title:
                            title = self.app
                        self.title = title
                        print('onFocus() RESULT: ' + self.app + ' - ' + self.title)
            except Exception as e:
                print("onFocus() ERROR: " + str(e))
                pass

        def startMonitoring(self):
            try:
                print('startMonitoring()')
                pyatspi.Registry.registerEventListener(self.onFocus, "object:state-changed:focused")
                pyatspi.Registry.registerEventListener(self.onFocus, "object:state-changed:active")
                pyatspi.Registry.registerEventListener(self.onEvent, "object")
                pyatspi.Registry.start()
            except Exception as e:
                print("startMonitoring() ERROR: " + str(e))
                pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        pyatspiMonitor = PyatspiMonitor()
        pyatspiMonitor.startMonitoring()
   ```

So, again, my question is, how can I find out the app name and title of the currently active window in Ubuntu 22.04?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has not been released yet, and is not supported here. However, check if switching to the X.Org session helps.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist in 22-X.Org. It only exists in 22-Wayland. Still in need of a solution, ideally BEFORE 22 is released, so that my customers don't get angry when they move to 22 and my software breaks.

Comment: @gcdev I get that you need a solution, but 22.04 isn't supported on Ask Ubuntu until it releases. You could try the `#ubuntu-next` channel [in Ubuntu IRC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList)

Comment: The release date refers to **ISO release date for new installs**; no upgrades are offered for existing users.  The *gates* open for 21.10 users to upgrade first, with the *gates* for 20.04 users not planned to be opened for months (that doesn't occur until **after** 22.04.1's release).  You still have months if your *customers* are using a LTS release.  Also 22 is a different product to 22.04; Ubuntu Core 22 comes out much later than Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on which it is based; again months.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: Highly interesting question, though. Please repost on 21 april. Yes, this is Wayland making such things very difficult.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet? Is one of the solutions working again?